# Get the SQL query issued by a LINQ command in Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I grab the SQL that will be issued by a LINQ to SQL command and store it in a string in my C# code.  I do not want to have it sent to console out, not do I want to analyze it separately in SQL Studio or LinqPad.  I want to have that string so that my program can do what it wants with the string.  (In reality, I will send it to log4net, but that's incidental).

Does anyone know how to get this?  I know that the SQL is not actually issued to the database until you start walking through the iterators, but I am hoping that perhaps there is a way to get the SQL beforehand.

Comment: Is this LINQ to SQL, or Entity Framework?

Comment: ok, I updated the title and content to specify linq 2 sql.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the Entity Framework you can use the [`ToTraceString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring.aspx) method on an ObjectQuery like this:

```
ObjectQuery<Product> productQuery =
  from p in context.Products
  select p;

string sql = productQuery.ToTraceString();
```

If you are using Linq to Sql, you're DataContext has a [Log property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx) that you can use to get the Sql output.

```
    StringBuilder logBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    db.Log = new StringWriter(logBuilder);
    var custQuery =
        (from cust in db.Customers
        where cust.City == "London"
        select cust).ToList();

   string sql = logBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: this is Linq to SQL.  But I don't want it in the console, I want to have the actual string value to use.

Comment: @DanielWilliams I've updated my answer. Console was just an example. You can insert any TextWriter you want.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say if you are using Linq to SQL or EF, but with L2S, the database context object has a Log property that can be used for this purpose. You can learn more about this property [here](http://damieng.com/blog/2008/07/30/linq-to-sql-log-to-debug-window-file-memory-or-multiple-writers). Keep in mind you won't be able to execute the generated SQL without some modifications.